# KML generator/formatter for nodejs

Tags: node.js, kml, template-engine

I am storing GeoJSON data in mongodb through a nodejs endpoint.  I would like to create an endpoint to transform the GeoJSON data into KML.  I did a quick google and also checked the npm registry for a KML module but could not find one.

Anyone know of a KML plugin for node?  If not maybe an XML plugin that is configurable enough to easily generate KML?  I have seen a lot of templating modules around, not sure which one might be best to generate something like a KML file to send back to the user.

Comment: Hi. I wrote a small article about how I ended to handle the kml/kmz in nodejs - https://boobo94.github.io/tutorials/create-kml-kmz-nodejs/. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up rolling my own solution.  Imagine this is because KML is so verbose.

Answer (score -1):

A little bit of Googling came across [a web service that will do conversions](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) that is a web front end to the [ogr2ogr binary](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) (FLOSS, so you can get it yourself for your Node project).  There are even [precompiled binaries for various platforms](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries) that you could play with immediately.

A little more link following found [toGeoJSON](https://github.com/tmcw/togeojson), which is an NPM module that takes KML and converts it to GeoJSON, the opposite direction of what you're asking for.  See the [accompanying blog post](http://macwright.org/2013/01/02/togeojson.html) for another person's quest for what you are seeking.

Edit: Added second paragraph about toGeoJSON.

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately OGR is not as feature full as I would hope. Are there general XML to JSON converters?

Comment: How about https://code.google.com/p/x2js/ which is already in JavaScript, and thus ready for Node?